# Get the latest date from a text file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file with lots of dates as a string in it. I am trying to grab the latest date from that file using a shell command.

```
Dates
20171020
20171017
20180214 --This is latest date and needs to be returned 
20171206
20180122
README.md
```

Comment: I expect you can do it in one go with awk (or python or perl) but you could e.g. use grep or sed to filter out just the dates, then sort and head.

Comment: `grep -E '^[0-9]+$' FILE | uniq  | sort | tail -n1`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk `uniq` only remove _consecutive_ duplicates. Use `sort -u` instead. Not that duplicates would matter in this case.

Comment: @Biffen: I didn't know but I've just made a test and and it indeed does remove only consecutive duplicates. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of numeric sort:

```
$ sort -n README.md | tail -1
20180214
```

If it contains more than numbers only (and the dates are on the beginning of each line):

```
$ grep -oE '^[0-9]*' README.md  | sort -n | tail -1
20180214
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with a sortable date format that is in a number form, you can just do:

```
awk '($1>t){t=$1}END{print t}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(python3) vagrant@ubuntu:~$ cat test.txt
Dates
20171020
20171017
20180214
20171206
20180122
```

Now run some command

```
(python3) vagrant@ubuntu:~$ cat test.txt | sort -nr | head -1
20180214
```

Comment: [Useless use of `cat`!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) `sort -nr test.txt`